# How to use URLFOR in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, urlfor

```
How to load a background image in my lightning component. Here is my code.
**Header.css**
    .THIS body{
        background-image : url({!URLFOR($Resource.folder,'Images/BG.png')});
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: cover;

    }
```

It shows an error as follows.[image]

Comment: I dont think that direct URLFOR would work. Other way could be using url like /resource/folder/Image/BG.png.